# Allowing a flash movieclip to have a mask or smaller hit area advice

Tags: flash, mask, movieclip

There seems to be a lot of information regarding hitareas and masks in regards to movieclips, but I am posting my particular question in an attempt to gain some focus.  I am having a tough time figuring out which information actually applies to my situation.

I have a movieclip that I am having act as a button.  The PNG file that I am placing on this movieclip is that of a triangle arrow that is pointing to the right.  [image: arrow]

However, when I apply mouse events to my movieclip such as Mouse_Over, the entire movieclip seems to be a square. [image: arrow] (shown by the orange square here)  So when you hover your mouse close to the arrow, it triggers the mouse event without your mouse actually being on the visible portion of the image.

Which method is viable for allowing just the arrow to respond to mouse events, and not the square that also surrounds it?  Any information in how to accomplish this, or at least which method I am looking for, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you just made the image as small as posible wouldnt if be suficient?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately that approach would not be sufficient.